# BIOS does not detect SSD after graphic driver installation

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, data-recovery, hardware-failure

- I turned on my Windows 7 machine, checked my email, installed an auto-update to AMD Catalyst to version 13.1, installation proceeded as normal.  I did not immediately restart, but then proceeded to shut down my machine with no issue.

  - Came back later that day (after apx. 6 hours), turn on the machine, and I get one of these: 
    [image: Screenshot: Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key]
    "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"
  - I checked my BIOS for my OCZ Vertex 2 SSD, it didn't detect it.
  - I proceeded to check the power/SATA cables, replaced multiple cables, eventually swapped it into the place of another hard drive, still nothing.
  - I burned a copy of OCZ Tools and booted with it, still didn't detect the hard drive.
  - I moved the hard drive to another machine, booted it with OCZ tools, still didn't detect the hard drive.

My guess is the hard drive simply fried, but I have no clue how to deal with SSDs.  Basically what I would like to do is just salvage the data, but it appears so much like some sort of issue with the firmware on the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the drive is dead.

Reasons:

1. You can no longer detect the SSD in the BIOS, before an OS and drivers are loaded. This makes it a hardware problem and not a software problem. (In other words, ignore the GPU driver update)
2. You did proper checking with other cables and an other computer, ruling out problems with the motherboard and the cables.

That just leaves the drive.

I would not mind being proven wrong, but I see no way to recover the data from an SSD which no longer gets detected in any way at all. The only option I see is a new drive and a restore fro backups.

Comment: Do you think OCZ customer support would attempt to fix the drive or just give me a new one?  How can I be sure the personal data on the drive is safely removed prior to RMAing the drive? :(

Comment: Depends on what is wrong with it. Usually it is faster/cheaper for them just to sent a new one. As to personal data, not way to remove that without a working drive or voiding warranty.